# why isnt it staying inside the loop, do while in c

Tags: c, loops, do-while

this is my code

```
int main()
{
  char komut,komut2;
  do{
    scanf("%c",&komut);
    switch(komut){
    case 's':
    case 'S':
      kare();
    case 'r':
    case 'R':
      dikdortgen();
    case 't':
    case 'T':
      scanf("%c",&komut2);
      if(komut2=='u' || komut2=='U')
        ust_ucgen();
      if(komut2=='d' || komut2=='D')
        alt_ucgen();
    }
  }while(komut==!'e'||komut==!'E');

  return 0;
}
```

the problem is program running just for 1 input ı want it to run till ı give e or E input how can ı solve this?

Comment: Please, please, please learn to use the formatting tools correctly. There's a button marked *code* that automatically indents your text 4 spaces, and renders it as code.  Go delete all of those `<br>`s and format your code correctly.

Comment: Also, for clarity, try to use English names for variables and functions. Else it may be hard to parse what is meant to do what.

Comment: `while(komut==!'e'||komut==!'E');` --> `while(komut != 'e' && komut != 'E');`

Comment: sorry for non english variables  and ı will try to fix formatting

Comment: @user220910 is your problem solved or do you need more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First your `case` statement must end with a `break;`!

Then also you have to change `==!` to `!=` and in your `do...while` loop you have to change the condition from `||` to `&&`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 

    char komut, komut2;

    do{ 
        scanf(" %c", &komut); 

        switch(komut){ 
            case 's': 
            case 'S': 
                kare();
                 break;
            case 'r': 
            case 'R': 
                dikdortgen();
                break; 
            case 't': 
            case 'T': 
                scanf(" %c", &komut2); 

                if(komut2 == 'u' || komut2 == 'U') 
                    ust_ucgen(); 
                if(komut2 == 'd' || komut2 == 'D') 
                    alt_ucgen();
                break; 
        } 
    } while (komut != 'e' && komut != 'E'); 

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(komut==!'e'||komut==!'E');` is the incorrect part. You should use `!=` for the inequality.

Using `==!` makes it `komut == (!'e')` which means that `komut is equal to not 'e'`, which is `komut == 0`.